# how to calculate how many line has a specific word

Tags: python

I'm not sure if the if statement is wrong? I tried to split each line and iterate through each index and find 'the raven' and return the count.

```
def count_word(file_url, word):
    r = requests.get(file_url, stream=True)
    count = 0

    for line in r.iter_lines():
        words = line.split()
        if line[1:] == 'the raven':
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, make sure to include information about 1) what you expect to happen, and 2) what is happening instead.

Comment: It just returns none

Comment: by "how many line has a specific word" do you mean "in how many lines a specific word appears"?

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
`words = line.split()`
```

you're assigning to the variable `words` a list of strings - the non-whitespace strings in the line. But you're not doing anything with `words` after that. Instead, you do:

```
if line[1:] == 'the raven':
```

which checks if the whole line, minus its first character, is exactly 'the raven'.

(Edited for handing unicode/bytes): If you want to add up the total number of times 'the raven' appears in your whole file, you can skip the `split` and the `if` and get the count of occurrences directly from each line. Because requests gives you `bytes` objects (in python 3) or `unicode` objects (in python 2) you'll need to decode the lines with the appropriate encoding first:

```
for line in r.iter_lines():
    count += line.decode('utf-8').count('the raven')
```

If instead you want to return the total number of lines in which 'the raven' appears at all, you can do:

```
for line in r.iter_lines():
    if 'the raven' in line.decode('utf-8'):
        count += 1
```

You may need to choose a different encoding, depending on your data source.

Comment: I tried all of these already but it kept giving me this error: "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: Ah, sorry - didn't realize you were using python 3. In that case you'll need to decode your input. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following slight edits to your code will allow you to count any word as defined by the parameter `word` in the file defined by `file_url`.

```
def count_word(file_url, word):
    r = requests.get(file_url, stream=True)
    count = 0

    for line in r.iter_lines():
        count += line.count(word)

    return count
```